# PySDL2 and SDL_GetKeyboardState

Tags: python, keyboard, ctypes, sdl-2, pysdl2

I'm trying to learn SDL via PySDL2 (currently version 0.7.0; [source](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2) / [documentation](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). It provides a [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) Python wrapper to (I assume) all of SDL's normal functions, and it provides a few more Pythonic functions via its `sdl2.ext` package to handle the nitty-gritty and return results in Python types. For example, `sdl2.ext.get_events()` will call `sdl2.SDL_PumpEvents()`, then peep at all the events on the queue and return them as a Python list.

However, I cannot tell if such a convenience function exists for `SDL_GetKeyboardState()`. The official [SDL Wiki documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) for the function defines it as:

```
const Uint8* SDL_GetKeyboardState(int* numkeys)
```

where numkeys may be null (otherwise it will receive the length of the returned array) and the returned Uint8* is a pointer to an array of key states, indexed by SDL_Scancode values, which will hold 1 if the key is down or 0 if it is up.

PySDL2 does provide a direct call to SDL_GetKeyboardState via `sdl2.keyboard.SDL_GetKeyboardState(numkeys)`, but that returns a ctypes value that is not immediately useful.

So my question is, **is there some more Pythonic function for getting the current SDL keyboard state via PySDL2**? If there is, what is it and how should it be used? If there's not, should one be submitted?

For reference, I think I figured out how to achieve this functionality myself, but it was a rough baptism in ctypes so I might have mangled something:

```
import ctypes
import sdl2


KEYBOARD_ARRAY_TYPE = ctypes.c_uint8 * sdl2.SDL_NUM_SCANCODES


def get_keyboard_state():
    """ Returns a pointer to the current SDL keyboard state,
    which is updated on SDL_PumpEvents. """
    raw_keystate = sdl2.keyboard.SDL_GetKeyboardState(None)
    pointer = ctypes.cast(raw_keystate, ctypes.POINTER(KEYBOARD_ARRAY_TYPE))
    return pointer.contents
```

Comment: You could probably determine this yourself by downloading the source code for SDL and grepping for "GetKeyboardState". In any case, in many cases it is more helpful to use `GetEvents()` and track the state of the keyboard yourself instead of using `GetKeyboardState()`. You are often trying to determine that a key is pressed. Repeatedly querying the state of the keyboard means you need to ensure you query it fast enough to not miss presses.

Comment: I had originally checked for key presses, but that was leading to choppy behavior when I wanted held buttons. As in, I could observe my Windows repeat rate coming into play when trying to move a sprite to the right. That and it didn't appear to repeat down and right simultaneously. I agree that it's often important to know if a key was pressed (or released), but sometimes one also wants to know which key(s) are currently down. I'll see what I can do about grepping the source; it hadn't even occurred to me as I always have trouble finding that Bitbucket site I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modification that uses `numkeys` instead of the constant `SDL_NUM_SCANCODES`:

```
import ctypes
import sdl2

def get_keyboard_state():
    """ Returns a list with the current SDL keyboard state,
    which is updated on SDL_PumpEvents. """
    numkeys = ctypes.c_int()
    keystate = sdl2.keyboard.SDL_GetKeyboardState(ctypes.byref(numkeys))
    ptr_t = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8 * numkeys.value)        
    return ctypes.cast(keystate, ptr_t)[0]
```

Comment: It's interesting to note that the difference between having a pointer and having a list is that the contents of the pointer are automatically updated by SDL_PumpEvents, whereas the list captures the state at the time at which it was created (meaning it must be rerun to be useful). My gut says that this is more Pythonic but less efficient than my attempt. I'll give it some time to see if anyone digs up a more official PySDL2 function that I'm unaware of.

Comment: That's a good point. I changed it to return the static array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution that does not require importing `ctypes`:

```
keystatus = sdl2.SDL_GetKeyboardState(None)
if keystatus[sdl2.SDL_SCANCODE_W]:
    print("the w key was pressed")
```